# EXCEL formula or macro to search "world" string but it should not count "worldwide" in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

list of data the result should contain "world" word but it should not give "worldwide". Result should not give search key as substring

Comment: This is not the correct forum to ask such question.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to count number of cells in a range containing a particular word. You can use **User Defined Function** for this.
In the VBA editor, go to the Insert menu, choose Module and add the following code.

```
Function CountWord(searchStr As String, rng As Range) As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim arr() As String
    count = 0
    For Each cel In rng
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            arr = Split(cel.Value, " ")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If StrComp(arr(i), searchStr, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    count = count + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
    CountWord = count
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE :** Above function will count number of cells containing specified word i.e. if specified word occurs more than once in a cell it will still be counted as 1.  If you want to count the number of occurrence of a word in a range then just remove `Exit For` in `If` condition.